# How to unmarshall incoming request payload as method/function arguments based on content type in Python flask or bottle frameworks

Tags: python, flask

Is it possible to unmarshall incoming request payload as method/function arguments in bottle or flask? If so, how?

I would like to send say following as request payload of a POST/PUT request,

```
{ 'foo': [ 'bar1', 'bar2'], 'spam': 2 }
```

and have this used in pseudocode as,

```
@route('/cheeseshop/<id>', method='PUT')
def cheeseShop(foo, spam):
    pass
```

Can this be done automatically looking at the content type in either of these frameworks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some caveats in doing so for code readability but a possible solution is as follow.

Define the serialization method. If you need to work with different clients I suggest `JSON`.

Create a *decorator* and put it between your `function` and the `route`

```
@route(...)
@expandargs
def foo(id, bar, baz):
    ...
```

In the decorator use `request.json()` (automatically decodes the payload if it's `JSON`) to expand the args and then you'll call the wrapped function with original `args` and the new, say, `**expandedargs` (note the double asterisks to explode the keywords).

Problems arise when mixing positional and keyword args.

Comment: Thanks - I see what you mean. I thought there might be something built in to these frameworks that I couldn't find.

Answer (score 0):

This is of cause just sketching out Paolos answer, but to aid anyone else looking for this, here's an example of an unmarshalling decorator that accomplishes the goal.

```
from functools import wraps
def unmarshal_payload(view):
    @wraps(view)
    def unmashalled_view(*args, **kwargs):
        return view(*args, **request.get_json(), **kwargs)
    return unmashalled_view
```

Which would then be used as:

```
@app.route(f'/<int:id>/', methods=['PUT'])
@unmarshal_payload
def view(id, foo, bar):
    print(id, foo, bar)
    return 'Success'
```

Then depending on how you want to handle things like the payload containing `{'id': 'something'}` you can change it. As it is in this naive implimentation, Flask will return an Internal Server Error, as python throws a TypeError due to a function recieving multiple keyword arguments for the same keyword. Also if you give have parameters that are not named in the view, you get a Type Error with Unexpected keyword.

So a slightly more lenient definition would be:

```
from functools import wraps
def unmarshal_payload(view):
    @wraps(view)
    def unmashalled_view(*args, **kwargs):
        return view(*args, **kwargs, **{k:v for k,v in request.get_json().items() if k not in kwargs})
    return unmashalled_view 

@app.route(f'/<int:id>/', methods=['PUT'])
@unmarshal_payload
def view(id, foo, bar, **kwargs):
    print(id, foo, bar)
    return 'Success'
```